# Setting wallpaper in NetBSD JWM

Tags: wallpaper, netbsd

I have installed "NetBSD JWM" in the virtual environment of VMware Workstation 14 Pro.
I'd like to set wallpaper but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To [quote the authors](http://joewing.net/projects/jwm/config-2.3.shtml),

> Configuration of JWM is done by editing ".jwmrc".
>
> [...]
>
> Virtual desktops are controlled with the Desktops tag. Within this tag the following attributes are supported.
>
> - *width* The number of virtual desktops in the horizontal direction. The default is 4.
> - *height*
>     The number of virtual desktops in the vertical direction. The default is 1.
>     Within the Desktops tag the following tags are supported.
>
>   - *Background*
>       The default background for desktops. The type attribute determines the type of background and the text contained within this tag is the value.
>
>     Valid types are:
>
>     - *solid* A solid color. See Colors. This is the default.
>     - *gradient* A gradient color. See Colors.
>     - *image* A stretched image.
>     - *scale* A scaled image.
>     - *tile* A tiled image.
>     - *command* A command to be run for setting the background.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christopher.

I set it up as below.

    <!-- Virtual Desktops -->
    <!-- Desktop tags can be contained within Desktops for desktop names. -->
    <Desktops width="4" height="1">
        <!-- Default background. Note that a Background tag can be
              contained within a Desktop tag to give a specific background
              for that desktop.
         -->
        <Background type="solid">#7CFC00</Background>

I'm really thankful to you.

Comment: What kind of command is "command A command to be run for setting the background."?

Comment: A command to display a movie or animated gif or some program output..

Comment: Is that thing like "imagemagick & ffmpeg" etc?
Because I do not have much knowledge and skills,
         <Background type = "solid"> # 7 CFC00 </ Background>

What kind of description is required after this?

Is it possible to specifically teach me a professor?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background image interactively if you install `feh`.

```
feh --no-fehbg --bg-fill some-image.jpg
```

(I use the optional `--no-fehbg` switch to avoid writing the `~/.fehbg` file.)